# Ant build failure

Tags: build, ant, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am trying to build my project using ant but it keeps on failing. It says

```
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ..."
```

and sometimes:

```
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: gc overhead limit exceeded "
```

I tried to increase the heap space by

```
ANT_OPTS = -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Still same problem. I am not able to find any other solution. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: what are you running? Which target and whats the target is?

Comment: my targets are: test -> buildComponent -> testFramework -> cleanComponent -> init -> clean -> build

Comment: ok great that's the reason why its not working. it should be somewhere in test. check that out and you should be bale to make out.